# Как записать в google таблицу данные с формы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста с php скриптом. Необходимо получить данные с формы на сайте и записывать их в свободную строку в Excel таблице на Google диске.

Comment: Приведите код, который у вас не работает

Comment: 1. Установил через composer "google-api-php-client" и "php-google-spreadsheet-client". Подключил require 'vendor/autoload.php'; В https://console.developers.google.com создал "сервисный аккаунт" для своей учетной записи google. Взял с Wiki функцию для получения токен: http://goo.gl/8BHDpD    Дальше использую токен при следующих вызовах: 
$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

(Делаю все по инструкциям с GitHab-а относительно данных библиотек). В ответ от "php-google-spreadsheet-client" получаю "Invalid token" :(